# Help $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1-e^{-kt}}{k}=? $

Tags: limits

what is the lime of $ \frac{1-e^{-kt}}{k}$ as $k \to \infty$?

Is that just equal $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$?

Does any one can help, I am not sure if We can apply L'Hopital's rule. S

Comment: Why do you need L'Hopital's rule? denominator goes to infinity and numerator is bounded when $t\geq 0$, your estimation is correct. When $t<0$, you need the rule.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

If $t=0,e^{-kt}=1$

If $t>0, \lim_{k\to\infty}e^{-kt}=0$

If $t<0, t=-r^2$(say), $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1-e^{-kt}}k=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1-e^{kr^2}}k=\frac\infty\infty $

So, applying L'Hospitals' rule, $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1-e^{kr^2}}k=-r^2\cdot\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{e^{r^2t}}1=-r^2\cdot\infty=-\infty$

Comment: @user58228, welcome. Hope I could make the idea clear